# Laravel - understanding Job concept

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

Dealing with Laravel queue, what I understand is job is the task that is kept in the queue to be performed one after another.

The Laravel doc says :

> In other words, if you dispatch a job without explicitly defining
>   which queue it should be dispatched to, the job will be placed on the
>   queue that is defined in the queue attribute of the connection
>   configuration:
>
> // This job is sent to the default queue...
>
> ```
> Job::dispatch();
> ```
>
> // This job is sent to the "emails" queue...
>
> ```
> Job::dispatch()->onQueue('emails');
> ```

In another place in the same doc page, I find:

```
 ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast);
```

`ProcessPodcast` is a job here which is being dispatched with an argument i.e. `$podcast`.  But nowhere in the doc I found the syntax `Job::` except in the mentioned 2 lines.

**Q1)** So where and how to use the syntax `Job::` ?

Every element in the `connections` array inside `config/queue.php` has  `'queue' => 'default',`.

**Q2)** Where does the `emails` queue come from in `Job::dispatch()->onQueue('emails');` ?

Comment: you are literally showing an example using that syntax ... `ProcessPodcast::....` that is a **job**. In the example `Job` is a placeholder for your job class you made

Comment: `Job::` in the line rather seems to be a particular facade . Should the doc be more unambiguous  ?

Comment: its not a facade ... there is no facade named `Job` ... it is a generic word like saying `Class`, you name your jobs not laravel, they don't know what your jobs are called, you have to infer your own classes

Comment: I meant it seems to be a facade while it is not.

Comment: its called a static method call, its just PHP ... just like you use static method calls with your models, they are not facades

Answer (score 2):

**A1:** Like [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) said, Job is a generic name for any job you would create and dispatch.

**A2:** The queues don't need to be defined anywhere, you just tell Laravel wich queue you want to dispatch a job to and that's it. For example, if you call `Job::dispatch()->onQueue('emails');` for the database connection, a new row will be created in the queue jobs table (the table name is `jobs` by default), and the column `queue` will be filled with `emails`. After that, this job will only be executed if you run a worker specifying the emails queue: `php artisan queue:work --queue=emails`. If the default queue for the database connection specified in config/queue.php file is the emails queue, then you don't need to specify the queue when running the worker command.

If you have many queues, you can create one process for each one, so you can define how you'd like to run each jobs queue.

Comment: Note using laravel horizon you can specify what queues you have in the config :)

Answer (score 0):

> So where and how to use the syntax Job:: ?

You can use it anywhere, while you can also use the helper `dispatch()` or implement the trait `DispatchesJobs` and call `$this->dispatch()`. All these calls are gonna work, create your job object and dispatch it.

> Where does the emails queue come from in Job::dispatch()->onQueue('emails'); ?

Queues are dependent on which driver you run, if you run horizon you are going to need to change the config (and still start the system process). Are you running other queue drivers, you will have to create the queues on the server that should run them `php artisan queue:work redis --queue=emails`.

Which of these queues the job is dispatched too, is dependant on which queue is specified in the onQueue() call, for maintainability and securing the jobs runs on the correct queue, i prefer to set it in on the job.

```
class job implements ShouldQueue {
    public $queue = 'emails';
}
```

Comment: ` protected $queue = 'emails';` - where is it in the Laravel doc ?

Comment: That is taken from the source code, laravel documentation is a help to get going but sometimes it is a good habbit to check it https://github.com/illuminate/bus/blob/b6da517d2cdbbf707c2df3e170e1e1a08a94863e/Queueable.php#L75. Alternatively you can call onQueue('emails') in the constructor of the job.

Comment: The doc you mentioned has `public $queue;` instead of `protected $queue`

Comment: oh yes wrote it in "as i remembered" again alternative call onQueue in the constructor